# Intermediate Algebra- Advanced Polynomial Forms

Tags: polynomials

There is a problem I just don't understand. I tried so many things with $f(x)=d(x)q(x)+r(x)$ but I just can't come to an answer. I checked the answer explanation and its extremely vague. This is the question:

When the polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $x^3 + x + 1,$ the remainder is $3$.  When the polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $x^3 - x + 1,$ the remainder is $x + 1.$ Let $r(x)$ be the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^6 + 2x^3 - x^2 + 1.$ Find $r(2).$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note $(x^3+x+1)(x^3-x+1)=x^6+2x^3-x^2+1$

Comment: is the answer $3$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The answer is 83/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with calculating the Bézout relation
$$(x^2+1)(x^3-x+1)-(x^2-1)(x^2+x+1)=2\text{.}$$
Note that the difference in the remainders is $x-2$. Multplying both sides of the relation by this expression and cancellation give
$$(2x^2-1)(x^3+x +1)-(2x^2+3)(x^3-x+1)=2(x-2)\text{.}$$
Thus
$$(2x^2-1)(x^3+x+1)+2(3)= (2x^2+3)(x^3-x+1)+2(x+1)$$
so that the remainder of $2f$ when divided by $(x^3+x+1)(x^3-x+1)$ must be given by either side of this last equality, i.e.,
$$2f(x)\equiv 2x^5+x^3+2x^2-x+5\pmod{(x^3-x+1)(x^3+x+1)}$$
whence $2r(2)=83$.

Comment: +1 you got the correct answer according to OP; could you explain where I went wrong with my answer before I delete it?

Answer (score 0):

$f(2)\equiv 3\bmod x^3+x+1$; $f(2)\equiv3\bmod x^3-x+1$;

by the constant case of the Chinese remainder theorem,

$f(2)\equiv3\bmod (x^3+x+1)(x^3-x+1)=x^6+2x^3-x^2+1$.

But if the answer is $83/2,$ then this is wrong.

Comment: Do you by any chance understand this part of the solution:( First Part) - We can write
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= (x^6 + 2x^3 - x^2 + 1) q(x) + r(x) \\
&= (x^3 + x + 1)(x^3 - x + 1) q(x) + r(x),
\end{align*}for some polynomial $q(x).$ We are told that when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^3 + x + 1,$ the remainder is 3. From the equation above, this is the same as the remainder when $r(x)$ is divided by $x^3 + x + 1,$ so
\[r(x) = (x^3 + x + 1) q_1(x) + 3.\]

Comment: I just don't understand how that is the same as the remainder when r(x) is divided by $x^3+x+1$ like why would they even do that???

Comment: What this kind of argument can actually show is that
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=3\mod{(x-2,x^3+x+1)} & f(x)&=3\mod{(x-2,x^3-x+1)}\text{;}
\end{align}$$
that is,
$$\begin{align}
f(2)&=3\mod{(11)} & f(2)&=3\mod{(7)}
\end{align}$$
so that $f(2)=3\pmod{77}$.. And certainly, $\tfrac{83}{2}=3\pmod{77}$.

Comment: Thanks so much, @KBDave.  Do you think I should delete my answer?